# How to catch WebApplicationException with JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am trying to catch `WebApplicationException` with my `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper` class but I get a strange behavior.

**This is my simple rest method:**

```
@GET
@Path("/saySomething")
public List<String> saySomething() {
    String response = EchoRestClient.ping();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(response);
    list.add("okay");
    return list;
}
```

**(1st) This is the client class which calls another rest api:**

```
public class EchoRestClient {
    private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    public static String ping() {
        String serviceUrl = PropertyReader.getProperty(ServiceUrl.ECHO_SERVICE);

        Response response = client
                .target(serviceUrl)
                .path("saySomething")
                .request(ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_UTF8)
                .get();

        if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            return response.getEntity(String.class);
        }

        throw new WebApplicationException(response);
    }
}
```

**And my custom Exception handler, which does NOT catch the above thrown exception:**

```
@Provider
public class WebservletExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {

        System.out.println("caught exception");
        Response response;

        if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
            response = ((WebApplicationException) exception).getResponse();
        } else {
            response = Response....build();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

(2nd) BUT if I do this the exception is caught (EchoRestClient.java):

```
public static String ping() {
    // same code then before

    WebApplicationException e = new WebApplicationException(response);
    throw new RuntimeException("xxxxxx", e);
}
```

My code above works fine and I get a proper response when I call the `saySomething` rest method from my web browser.

BUT if I undeploy the `EchoService` rest (contains the called `ping` rest method) the HTTP 404 is not caught in the 1st case. I need to throw a RuntimeException because WebApplicationException is not caught (2nd case).

According to the documentation the exception hierarchy is WebApplicationException extends RuntimeException.

What is wrong here?

**-- EDIT --**

If I throw this exception then it is caught fine: `throw new WebApplicationException(response.getStatus())`

But this one does not work: `throw new WebApplicationException(response)`

Is something wrong in the response object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by an issue in Jersey. If your code throws a WebApplicationException that contains a Response object, ExceptionMappers are not called.

See also:

- https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3716
- [ExceptionMapper not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732408/exceptionmapper-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.